# The length of the shortest $s$-$t$ path equals the maximum tension between $s$ and $t$

Tags: graphs, optimization, shortest-path, linear-programming

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Consider a directed graph $G = (V, A)$ with start vertex $s ∈ V$, target vertex $t \in V$ and weights $w_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ for each arc $(i, j)\in A$. For any $i \in V$ let further be $\pi_i \in \mathbb{R}$ be the so-called **potential** of $i$. The potential difference $\tau_{ij} = \pi_i − \pi_j$ is called the **tension** of the arc $(i, j)$ with respect to the potential vector $\pi$. Finally, let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of all directed paths from $s$ to $t$.
>
> Now consider the following LP $(P)$:
> \begin{align}
>  \max& \sum_{(i,j) \in P} \tau_{ij}\\
>   s.t. & \qquad P \in \mathcal{P} \\
>   &  \qquad \tau_{ij} = \pi_i - \pi_j \text{ for all $(i,j) \in A$}\\
>   &  \qquad \tau_{ij} \le w_{ij} \text{ for all $(i,j) \in A$}\\
>   &  \qquad \pi_i \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for all $i \in V$}
>  \end{align}
>
> If $P^\ast$
> is a path for which the maximum in $\mathcal{P}$ is achieved, the value $\sum_{(i,j) \in P^\ast} \tau_{ij}$ is referred to as **maximum tension** between $s$ and $t$.
>
> Prove that under the assumption that an $s$-$t$ shortest path exists with respect to the arc weights
> $w_{ij}$, the length of a shortest $s$-$t$ path equals the maximum tension between $s$ and $t$.

If I am not mistaken we have by the definition of $\tau_{ij}$ that $\sum_{(i,j) \in P} \tau_{ij}  = \pi_s-\pi_t$, so the maximal tension is constant for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$. Could you please tell me what I am misunderstanding?

Remark: I know that this is supposed to be the dual of the shortest path problem, but I am supposed to do this directly.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in the exercise, "If $P^\ast$
is a path for which the maximum in $\mathcal{P}$ is achieved, the value $\sum_{(i,j) \in P^\ast} \tau_{ij}$ is referred to as **maximum tension** between $s$ and $t$." is indeed quite confusing.

As you have pointed out, given $i\to\pi_i$ for all $i\in V$ and $\tau_{ij}=\pi_i-\pi_j$, we know the sum $\sum_{(i,j) \in P} \tau_{ij}  = \pi_s-\pi_t$ does not depend on the choice of $P \in \mathcal{P}$.

Here is an equivalent but clearer definition of the maximum tension.

Consider a directed graph $G = (V, A)$ with start vertex $s ∈ V$, target vertex $t ∈ V$ and weights $w_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ for each arc $(i, j)\in A$. Assume there is a path from $s$ to $t$.  Then the maximum tension of $(G, s, t, w)$ is the optimal value of the objective function of the the following linear program.  When $G$ and $w$ are understood, we also call it the maximum tension from $s$ to $t$.

$$\begin{array}{rl}
 \max&\pi_s-\pi_t\\
  s.t. &  \pi_i - \pi_j \le w_{ij} \text{ for all }(i,j) \in A\\
  &  \pi_i \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for all $i \in V$}
 \end{array}$$

The essential point here is that the assignment $\pi_i$ for all $i\in V$ are independent variables in the linear program above.